# custom web font provider

Tags: javascript, css, webfont-loader

I want to use google's web font loader with my own custom fonts on my own server.

I am a bit confused as to [how to configure](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) my own ***web-font provider*** as described in google's own documentation:

```
In addition to the google, typekit, ascender and monotype options, 
there is also a custom module that can load a stylesheet
from any web-font provider.

WebFontConfig = {
  custom: { families: ['OneFont', 'AnotherFont'],
    urls: [ 'http://myotherwebfontprovider.com/stylesheet1.css',
      'http://yetanotherwebfontprovider.com/stylesheet2.css' ] }
};
```

What should my external css contain in order to work with this library?

Comment: Well... A font-face definition I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at @font-face kits, somewhere like font squirrel is a good place to start. You can save the various file formats like woff, svg etc into an fonts folder, add the css that the @font face kit provides to a stylesheet of your own and then call it in your head along with the rest of your CSS, as soon as you read the docs on the site it will make sense, any further help then feel free to ask